# How to Convert a Normal Dataframe into MultiIndex'd based on certain condition

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multi-index

After a long While I visited to the SO's pandas section and got a question which is not indeed nicely framed thus thought to put here in an explicit way as similar kind of situation I'm too as well :-)

Below is the data frame construct:

```
>>> df
       measure      Pend Job       Run Job       Time
cls
ABC  [inter, batch]     [101, 93]   [302, 1327]  [56, 131]
DEF  [inter, batch]  [24279, 421]  [4935, 5452]  [75, 300]
```

### Desired output would be...

I tried working hard but didn't get any solution, thus though to Sketch it here as that's somewhat I would like it be achieved.

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |                 |Pend Job     |       Run Job       |     Time             |
cls | measure         |-----------------------------------------------------------
    |                 |inter | batch|       |inter | batch|     |inter | batch   |
----|-----------------|------|------|-------|------|------|-----|------|----------                    
ABC |inter, batch     |101   |93    |       |302   |1327  |     |56    |131      |
----|-----------------|-------------|-------|------|------|-----|------|---------|
DEF |inter, batch     |24279 |421   |       |4935  |5452  |     |75    |300      |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Saying that I want my dataFrame into MultiIndex Dataframe where `Pend Job` ,  `Run Job`,  and `Time` to be on the top as above.

### Edit:

`cls` is not in the columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is my approach, you can modify it to your need:

```
s = (df.drop('measure', axis=1)                   # remove the measure column
       .set_index(df['measure'].apply(', '.join), 
                  append=True)                    # make `measure` second level index
       .stack().explode().to_frame()              # concatenate all the values
    )

# assign `inter` and `batch` label to each new cell
new_lvl = np.array(['inter','batch'])[s.groupby(level=(0,1,2)).cumcount()]
# or
# new_lvl = np.tile(['inter', 'batch'], len(s)//2)

(s.set_index(new_level, append=True)[0]
  .unstack(level=(-2,-1)
  .reset_index()
)
```

Output:

```
   cls       measure Pend Job      
                        inter batch
0  ABC  inter, batch      101    93
1  DEF  inter, batch    24279   421
```

Comment: Thanks for the update, I'll check that +1, However Just to confirm that `cls` is not in the columns which earlier looks to be, Sorry for the confusion Edited the post.

Comment: It gives an error like `KeyError: "None of ['cls'] are in the columns"`

Comment: I didn't notice that `cls` was the index of the original dataframe. See updated answer (the only change is in the definition of `s`).

Comment: `s.groupby(level=(0,1,2))` instead of just `(0,1)`. See updated.